# Database cannot be created

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried to create a database in Android using SQLite. I have a separate class that inserts the values into the database, but I'm getting an error that says the database cannot be created and I'm not sure why! Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.siuni.mymedicare;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by SiUni on 23/04/2015.
 */

public class MyDBHandler {

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "_firstname";
    public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "_surname";
    public static final String COLUMN_TELEPHONENO = "_telephoneno";
    public static final String COLUMN_POSTCODE = "_postcode";
    private static final String TAG = "MyDBHelper";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymedicare.db";
    private static final String TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER = "Databasehandler";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "name text not null, surname not null, telephoneno notnull, postcode not null);";
    public final Context context;
    private DatabaseHandler DBHandler;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MyDBHandler(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }


    public MyDBHandler open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHandler.close();
    }

    public long insertContact(String Firstname, String Surname, String Telephone,
                              String Postcode) {

        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, Firstname);
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, Surname);
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_TELEPHONENO, Telephone);
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_POSTCODE, Postcode);
        return db.insert(TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER, null, insertValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllContacts ()
    {
        return db.query(TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER, new String [] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,
    COLUMN_SURNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getContact (long rowId) throws android.database.SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER, new String[] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,
                COLUMN_SURNAME}, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null,null,null,null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return  mCursor;
    }

}
```

The error log:

```
05-12 16:50:07.348    2466-2466/com.example.siuni.mymedicare E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting _surname= _postcode= _telephoneno= _firstname=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Databasehandler (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Databasehandler(_surname,_postcode,_telephoneno,_firstname) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at com.example.siuni.mymedicare.MyDBHandler.insertContact(MyDBHandler.java:85)
            at com.example.siuni.mymedicare.register.onCreate(register.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

`private static final String TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER = "**Databasehandler**";`

In your code you use `TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER` as table name, but you don't have a table named `Databasehandler`.

As you can see from your database creation statement, you have only one table - `contacts`:
`"create table **contacts** (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "name text not null, surname not null, telephoneno notnull, postcode not null);"`

Comment: I've changed the "create table **contacts**" to  "create table **Databasehandler**" and there seems to be no errors being throw!!! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I've changed as above and its still saying no such table: Databasehandler!!!

Comment: Make sure you've removed an app from your device

Comment: I've unistalled and reinstalled the app still throwing the same error on logcat no such table: Databaseahndler

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert values to the `Databasehandler` table, and there is only one table, int your creation SQL, called `contacts`.  `create table contacts (_id integer pr....`
Just change the value of the  `String TABLE_DATABASEHANDLER = "Databasehandler";` variable

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the other solution worked for me